# programa en Java

Tags: java

Estimada comunidad me podrían dar un mano en el siguiente ejercicio en Java:

1) El club de corredores nos pide un programa para obtener estadísticas de la carrera de 10
km. El mismo consiste en ingresar, por teclado, el número de corredor, las
horas, los minutos y los segundos que tardo en realizar la carrera. Tener en cuenta que al
ingresar 0 como el número de corredor, finaliza el programa y debe mostrar por pantalla:
a) El ganador
b) El promedio en segundos de los corredores.
c) El porcentaje de corredores que realizaron la carrera en menos de una hora.
Programar y utilizar la función `devolverSegundos` que recibe como parámetros
horas, minutos y segundos.

He logrado armar la función la cual devuelve la cantidad de segundos por cada corredor pero no se me ocurre como podría sacar el promedio en segundo de los corredores, lo mismo con verificar cual fue el ganador (hay alguna manera de determinar cuantos ciclos se hicieron en un *loop* en este caso `while`)

comparto mi código hasta la fecha cualquier comentario o critica sera bienvenido!!

Muchas Gracias!

```
public class ejercicio05 {

    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int hrs, min, seg, numCorredor;

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero corredor: ");
        numCorredor = sc.nextInt();

        while (numCorredor != 0) {

            System.out.println("Ingrese horas");
            hrs = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese minutos");
            min = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese segundos");
            seg = sc.nextInt();

            devolverSegundos(hrs,min,seg);//Llamas a la función con los parametros

            System.out.println();//\n
            System.out.println();//\n

            System.out.println("Ingrese numero corredor: ");
            numCorredor = sc.nextInt();

        }

        if (numCorredor == 0) {
            System.out.println("Fin del programa");
        }

    }//Fin del Main



    /*Funcion Devolver Segundos*/

    public static int devolverSegundos(int num1, int num2,int num3){

        int total;

        total = (num1*3600)+(num2*60)+num3;

        System.out.println("Tiempo: "+num1+":"+num2+":"+num3);  
        System.out.println("Cantidad de segundos: "+total);

        return total;
    }
}//Fin de la Clase
```

Comment: De casualidad no te lo pidieron orientado a objetos? o por lo menos con un arreglo bidimensional que guarde el numero de corredor y el tiempo? Tu código no hará lo que buscas ya que en ningún momento guardas los datos de los corredores, tu retorno de la función devolverSegundos no lo almacenas en ninguna variable, y también el if del al final es innecesario pues de no cumplirse la condición del while simplemente se lo saltará y ejecutará el código que este a continuación. Un saludo, espero te haya quedado claro que estas atacando mal el problema desde mi punto de vista.

Comment: Por favor aclara bien como lo quieres solucionar para poder ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

`devolverSegundos(hrs,min,seg);`//si piensas llamarlo así, de tal modo que espera que lo almacenes en una variable porque el método te devuelve un `int`. Es preferible que tengas tu método en *public static void* si piensas llamarlo de esta manera:

```
//tu método
public static int devolverSegundos(int num1, int num2,int num3){

    int total;

    total = (num1*3600)+(num2*60)+num3;

    System.out.println("Tiempo: "+num1+":"+num2+":"+num3);  
    System.out.println("Cantidad de segundos: "+total);

    return total;
}
```

/*
el promedio de los corredores la forma mas viable es calcular cuantos segundos totales hizo los 10km y *cantSegTotal=10/duracionCarr*;
`duracionCarr` podes usar la función `devolverSeg` que te retorna el total en segundos del corredor.

Y si, se puede determinar cuantas veces se pasaron por un ciclo `while`, con un simple contador.

```
int cont=0;
while(sentencia)
{
    cont+=1;
    //y esta variable se va sumando cada vez que pase.
}
```

Comment: Frank Gracias por tus comentarios, pero se me complica pensar el contador a la hora de armar el ciclo "while(sentencia)", sumado a que supongo que el contador iria dentro del primer while??

Answer (score 0):

la respuesta que te paso es orientada a objetos; no realizo el código directamente en el main.
He creado el método ***menu(Scanner)***; el bucle while funciona con un booleano para comprobar que el numero de corredor es distinto a 0, si se da el caso, ingresa corredores nuevos en el arraylist **corredores**. También comprueba que haya corredores ingresados para seguir con el programa.

```
 /**
         * Se añaden corredores al arraylist corredores mientras el numero de corredor sea diferente a 0.
         * Una vez que se ingrese el 0, no se pueden añadir más corredores.
         * @param reader es el Scanner para ingresar valores por teclado.
         */
        public void menu(Scanner reader) {
            boolean añadir=false;
            while(añadir!=true) {

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero corredor: ");
        numcorredor = reader.nextInt();

        if(numcorredor==0) {
            añadir = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Ingrese horas");
            hora = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese minutos");
            min = reader.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese segundos");
            seg = reader.nextInt();

            corredores.add(new Corredor(numcorredor, hora, min, seg));
        }
    }

    if(corredores.size()==0) {
        System.out.println("Debe participar al menos un corredor.");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No se pueden añadir más corredores.");
        mostrarPromedios();
    }
}
```

El metodo de ***devolverSegundos(int,int,int)*** es similar al tuyo.

```
/**
     * Calcula los segundos totales del corredor en realizar la carrera;
     * muestra también el tiempo total que ha tardado.
     * @param h son las horas
     * @param m son los minutos
     * @param s son los segundos
     */
    public int devolverSegundos(int h, int m, int s) {

    int total = (h*3600)+(m*60)+s;
    System.out.println("Tiempo: "+h+":"+m+":"+s);  
    System.out.println("Cantidad de segundos: "+total);
    return total;
}
```

Luego el método ***mostrarPromedios()*** recorre **corredores** y muestra la información de cada corredor; *promedio* se suma si el corredor no ha superado la hora. Terminado el for, calcula el porcentaje de corredores que no han superado la hora y lo muestra.

```
/**
     * Muestra el tiempo de cada corredor y calcula el porcentaje de aquellos que tardaron menos de 1 hora
     */
    public void mostrarPromedios() {

    int promedio=0;

    for(int recorre=0; recorre<corredores.size(); recorre++) {
        System.out.print("Nº corredor: "+corredores.get(recorre).getNumcorredor()+" ");
        devolverSegundos(corredores.get(recorre).getHora(), corredores.get(recorre).getMin(), corredores.get(recorre).getSeg());

        //si el corredor ha tardado menos de 1 hora
        if(corredores.get(recorre).getHora()<1) {
            promedio+=1;
        }
    }

    promedio = (promedio*100)/corredores.size();
    System.out.println("Porcentaje de corredores que acabaron en menos de 1 hora: "+promedio+"%");
}
```

Espero que te haya servido.

Answer (score 0):

mira me tomé la libertad de hacer un código que creo que podría funcionar. En este caso, lo que hice fue crear una clase corredor, haciendo que el tiempo (Horas, Minutos, Segundos), sean atributo de cada instancia de la clase corredor, para despues utilizar esos atributos como datos para sacar el promedio con la función obtenerPromedio.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class ejercicio05{
    private static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int numCorredor;
        float prom;
        ArrayList<Corredor> participantes = new ArrayList<Corredor>();

        System.out.println("Ingrese numero de corredor: ");
        numCorredor = sc.nextInt();

        while(numCorredor!=0){

            Corredor Competidor = new Corredor();

            Competidor.setCorredor(numCorredor);
            System.out.println("Ingrese horas: ");
            Competidor.setHoras(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Ingrese minutos: ");
            Competidor.setMinutos(sc.nextInt());
            System.out.println("Ingrese segundos: ");
            Competidor.setSegundos(sc.nextInt());

            // Devolvemos la información del tiempo
            Competidor.obtenerSegundos();

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");

            participantes.add(Competidor);
            prom = devolverPromedio(participantes);

            System.out.println("\n\nEl promedio es: "+prom+"\n\n");

            System.out.println("Ingrese numero corredor: ");
            numCorredor = sc.nextInt();
        }

        if(numCorredor == 0){
           System.out.println("Fin del programa");
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static float devolverPromedio(ArrayList<Corredor> vector){
        int total = 0;
        float promedio;
        Iterator<Corredor> iter = vector.iterator();

        while(iter.hasNext()){
            Corredor c = iter.next();
            total += c.obtenerSegundos();
        }

        promedio = total / vector.size();

        return promedio;
    }
}

class Corredor {
    private int numCorredor;
    private int horas;
    private int minutos;
    private int segundos;

    public Corredor(){
    }

    //SETTERS
    public void setCorredor(int numero){
        this.numCorredor = numero;
    }
    public void setHoras(int hora){
        this.horas = hora;
    }
    public void setMinutos(int minuto){
        this.minutos = minuto;
    }
    public void setSegundos(int segundo){
        this.segundos = segundo;
    }
    //GETTERS
    public int getCorredor(){
        return this.numCorredor;
    }
    public int getHoras(){
        return this.horas;          
    }
    public int getMinutos(){
        return this.minutos;
    }
    public int getSegundos(){
        return this.segundos;
    }

    //Métodos
    public int obtenerSegundos(){
        int total = 0;
        total = (this.getHoras() * 3600) + (this.getMinutos() * 60) + this.getSegundos();

        System.out.println("Tiempo: "+this.getHoras()+":"+this.getMinutos()+":"+this.getSegundos());
        System.out.println("Cantidad de segundos: "+total);

        return total;
    }
}
```